# See joins between oracle tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that shows me all tables for a given table space:

```
select tablespace_name, table_name from ALL_tables
where tablespace_name = 'final';
```

I'm looking to find out what/how tables are linked in the database/tablespace.

Is there a way to get select all primary keys that equal foreign keys? Or list of all the foreign keys and the keys they reference.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-9C96DA92-CFE0-4A3F-9061-C5ED17B43EFE.htm#REFRN20047

Answer (score 0):

try this -- add filter for owner or for table name

```
with col_list as
(select owner, constraint_name, listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by position) col_list
      from dba_cons_columns
      group by owner, constraint_name) 
select pk.owner, pk.constraint_name pk, fk.owner, fk.constraint_name fk, pk_cols.col_list, fk_cols.col_list 
from dba_constraints pk
join dba_constraints fk
on pk.constraint_name=fk.r_constraint_name
and pk.owner=fk.r_owner
and fk.constraint_type='R'
join col_list pk_cols
on pk_cols.constraint_name=pk.constraint_name
and pk_cols.owner=pk.owner
join col_list fk_cols
on fk_cols.constraint_name=fk.constraint_name
and fk_cols.owner=fk.owner
```